# Excel: IF ISBLANK Function Seeing 6 Additional Rows as Filled

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, named-ranges

The project I am working on has several components, so let me start from the beginning. From a calendar program, I am supposed to download a roster of individuals that have signed up for a course and input their names into a Sign-In Sheet. Later, once attendance has been verified, certificates are made for each person who showed up.

I have built a macro that takes the raw data from the calendar and builds the Sign-In Sheet around the list of names, alphabetizes, and formats everything as we need it with a click of a button.

The problem I am running into comes from the certificate portion of the process.

In order to speed up this part, we tried to create a second sheet behind the Sign-In sheet that would pull all the information needed on the Certificates into a separate list that could easily be mail merged into the certificate template.

Three columns in Sheet2 are user specific and change depending on raw data from the calendar. I got these cells to talk to Sheet1 just fine by using the =(Sheet1!A8) function, then copying is down.

However, the other three columns have to be filled from a single cell on Sheet1 that gets typed in after the macro is run (such as the date and location), so it has to be a dynamic link to Sheet1. In addition I need it to look at another range and stop filling in cells on Sheet2 when it encounters a blank cell, so we are not wasting time deleting unneeded information.

I got this working for the most part using =IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A$8:$A$207), "", (Sheet1!$B$2)), but for some reason, the formula is filling 6 extra rows that are actually blank within the A8:A207 range in Sheet1. For example, Sheet1 A8:A207 contains data up to A25, however, Sheet2 is filling in cells as if Sheet1 is filled up to A31.

I have checked these cells for spaces and hidden formulas that could throw off my IF ISBLANK formula, but have not met with any success.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing these 6 extra cells to fill and what I can do to fix it?

Many Thanks!

Comment: `ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A$8:$A$207)` will return false if *any* of the cells in the given range are not blank. Should you not check each row individually?

Comment: Hello cybernetic.nomad, Yes. I did check those cells for anything that could have triggered the formula. I even looked for anything that may have been hidden, but found nothing. All signs point to those cells being completely blank as far as I can tell. After those additional six lines, the formula works correctly, only filling in text on Sheet2 if additional rows are filled in within the A8:A207 range in Sheet1, but I can't for the life of me find what is making it think there is data in those six rows.

Comment: Is the formula you posted (`=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A$8:$A$207), "", (Sheet1!$B$2))`) the exact formula you use in your sheet? You use absolute referencing in it, suggesting that for every time it appears, it looks at the same cells. Is this really what you want? I would have thought checking each line individually (`=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A8), "", (Sheet1!$B$2))` would do what you describe

Comment: Oh my god! Yes! That is exactly what I needed it to do! You just saved me a bunch of time and a major headache. I knew it was a simple error on my part causing the issue, but I could figure out what it was. Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is the formula you posted (=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A$8:$A$207), "", (Sheet1!$B$2))) the exact formula you use in your sheet? You use absolute referencing in it, suggesting that for every time it appears, it looks at the same cells. Is this really what you want? I would have thought checking each line individually (=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A8), "", (Sheet1!$B$2)) would do what you describe – cybernetic.nomad